# Is a description of product development work suitable for a journal paper?

Tags: publications, journals, publishability

I have worked on a project to develop a machine which is a end-of-arm-tooling type. I am thinking about bringing this work to a journal paper.

It means the content might include product design information, hardware & software and testing data

Is this type of work suitable for a journal paper? So far, in my field of computer vision and robotics control, I rarely see such direction of publication. I am not sure it is popular in elsewhere branch

There's also a wondering I have is that the review section of this journal mostly will have to mention available similar industry products instead of mentioning other journal papers (I haven't been able to find journals talking about product designs somewhere). And it's clear that citing company products is a weak citation I personally think because the source is the company's website which is providing advertising information

Comment: Can you tell us what Journal you have in mind? The appropriate of your submission will very much depend on that.

Comment: @Wilson: this project is actually a bit off-topic of the research I am doing, therefore, I haven't reviewed or even known the relevant journals. If possible, could you suggest me some related to design of mechatronics machines, robotics, end-of-arm-tooling journals? SCI ones? I am not even sure whether these journals exist or in which category such topics are popular due to limited  access to certain journal databases from my school

Comment: @Wilson: I personally think if I know some similar journals, or I can estimate the  publication potential of my project by its citation i.e. cite company products/websites or the way it is written i.e. written about product design for application. I believe that if a product design has some innovative ideas, it is worth publication. But what if it is a general product design? because some people might think that any product has at least its market value, some usage value, then is it also worth a publication?

Answer (score 1):

Academic journals generally publish papers describing original research results that advance (or try to advance) a particular field of study.  Development of a product is not necessarily an original research result.

- Does your design involve a new approach or technique that has not previously been used in the field? Does it represent a new way of thinking about a problem? Then it may be an original research result.
- Is your design an application or straightforward extension of previously known techniques, possibly with some small tweaks and optimizations? Then it may be a great new product, but is probably not a research result.

Comment: Possible counterexamples:  Journal of Visualized Experiments, Review of Scientific Instruments.

Comment: @ff524: I'd rather say it's an application project integrating different known design and control techniques. The application sounds new but not yet verified through paper reviewing. And I likely believe such application can be provided by big industrial corporations as customized solution, kind of solution only known to the two parties. Therefore, it took me a great deal of time to search for it in Google Scholar, Engineering Village with very few and not convincing results

Comment: @ShawnLe If it advances human knowledge, it's a legitimate scientific result.

Comment: @jakebeal thanks for your comment! this extension is a broad and ambiguous notation for a young researcher. For example, he has to know a lot about the available pool of knowledge before knowing that his work has some new values or not. This is sometimes not possible for young researchers like me

Comment: @ShawnLe in order to publish a decent paper, you need to learn about the existing work in the field and/or find a mentor who is an expert in the field and can advise you on that. Part of writing a research paper (on any subject) is putting your work in the context of existing work in the field, and explaining how your work contributes something new.